# Post Process Message with Spring AMQP Annotation Driven Reply (@SentTo)

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm trying to use the `@SentTo` annotation to send my return value to a RabbitMQ exchange as per the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#async-annotation-driven-reply

If I need to set heraders, the documentation says to return `Message<OrderStatus>` and use the `MessageBuilder`.

However, I need to set the `correlationId` message property and the `MessageBuilder` doesn't have a way for me to set properties, only header.

How can a replicate what I'm currently doing here, using the `@SentTo` annotation?

```
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(
  amqpRoutingKey,
  orderStatus,
  message -> {
    message.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId(orderStatus.getCorrelationId().toString());
    return message;
  }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this API:

```
/**
 * Makes this builder's properties builder use a reference to properties.
 * @param properties The properties.
 * @return this.
 */
public MessageBuilder andProperties(MessageProperties properties) {
```

Or you can just get a result of that `MessageBuilder` and really call `message.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId()` instead.

**UPDATE**

Well, there is even this API in the `AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory` from has just released Spring AMQP:

```
/**
 * Set post processors that will be applied before sending replies.
 * @param beforeSendReplyPostProcessors the post processors.
 * @since 2.0.3
 */
public void setBeforeSendReplyPostProcessors(MessagePostProcessor... beforeSendReplyPostProcessors) {
```

**UPDATE2**

If you are stick with the `org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder`, then you should set an `AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID` header into that message and it will be properly remapped to the `CorrelationId`. However, looking into the code you don't need to do that:

```
/**
 * Post-process the given response message before it will be sent.
 * <p>
 * The default implementation sets the response's correlation id to the request message's correlation id, if any;
 * otherwise to the request message id.
 * @param request the original incoming Rabbit message
 * @param response the outgoing Rabbit message about to be sent
 */
protected void postProcessResponse(Message request, Message response) {
    String correlation = request.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId();

    if (correlation == null) {
        String messageId = request.getMessageProperties().getMessageId();
        if (messageId != null) {
            correlation = messageId;
        }
    }
    response.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId(correlation);
}
```

Comment: You are referring to `org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder`, but the documentation is using `org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder`. I can tell because, they're using a `withPayload` method which the latter has and the former doesn't. I'll try out one of your other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Thank you for the pointer! But again: you still can use an `org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder` - there is an appropriate check in the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter` as well.